# Styling dynamically added children nodes added to parent div in tailwind

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-elements

I am trying to migrate my site stacktips.com from Bootstrap to Tailwind CSS. At first sight, it looked easy and I was able to replace all my static HTML with tailwind classes. I am now stuck and do not understand how to style the dynamically added HTML.

Let's say in the following example, everything under `<article>` element is dynamically created content and I do not have control over adding the CSS classes directly on those elements.

```html
<article class="article-content">
    <p>some text</p>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>some text</p>
    <pre>some text</pre>
</article>
```

Need some help adding the styling to p, h2, and pre tags under `article-content` div. These styles need to be different from the global styles.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the [`@tailwindcss/typography` Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin), as it is described:

> The official Tailwind CSS Typography plugin provides a set of prose classes you can use to add beautiful typographic defaults to any vanilla HTML you don’t control, like HTML rendered from Markdown, or pulled from a CMS.

Otherwise, you can use [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants), like:

```html
<article class="article-content [&_p]:text-red-500">
```

Of which you could [refactor to variants in a Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants).